# Why does Tabbar background appear lighter?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have set the following blue background on several views and they all look the same...

[image]

When I set the same color (using a static property) on a TabBar using `BarBackgroundColor = Colors.MyBlue`, it appears lighter. It's not my screen because I've looked up the RGB from a screenshot. (In fact, these images are screen shots.)

[image]

Is this a feature or a bug?

Comment: this happens both in android and iOS?

Comment: It only happens on iOS.

Comment: i knew it.. it's a bug, i have encountered this once and other people have found that too: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/94233/ios-frame-background-color-and-tabbar-color-not-accurate, my solution was not good, i ditched the xamarin forms one and used the Syncfusion controller instead, i don't know if it's an opacity problem or just a render conflict, my advice is to create an custom render for the tabbar controller and on the iOS render set the color by yourself, maybe via a new blindable property? i'm following this question to see if someone has a solution for this

Comment: It seems to require setting in Forms and native to get a not quite so light background. Although it's still not correct. How odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `TabBar.Translucent = false` in the custom Renderer will fix the issue:

```
  [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(CustomTabbedPage))]
    namespace App131.iOS
    {
        public class CustomTabbedPage : TabbedRenderer
        {
            public CustomTabbedPage()
            {
                TabBar.Translucent = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Refer: [ios-bartintcolor-is-always-lighter-than-the-color-that-is-defined](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/25685/ios-bartintcolor-is-always-lighter-than-the-color-that-is-defined) and [translucent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbar/1623458-translucent?language=objc)